# How can I shrink a div when it has inline styling?

Tags: html

from a HTML editor, a user can write a greeting text, for example, the source code would be:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
  <span style="font-size:20px">
    <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif">Hej,</span>
  </span>
</p><br><br>
<p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px">
  <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif">
    <span style="color:#FF0000"><em>Du&nbsp;</em></span>
    <strong>kan skrive</strong>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#0000CD"><u>din hilsen</u></span> her!</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

witch translates from

[image]

and when they click that big green "save" button, I show a simple preview such as

[image]

my problem is that the preview is not propotional to what will be printed and I can't seam to use any CSS to style the wrapped `<div>` around that text in order to show it a little bit more in prespective...

I wanted to shrink by 25%... is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Did you try using `!important`?

Comment: Wrap the content in another DIV when you grab your data? Like, `$data = "<div style=\"width:75%;\">" . htmlentities($_POST["greeting"]) . "</div>";` that way it would be 75% (or 25% less) of the parent DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css3

```
#class:target{     -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
-moz-transform: scale(0.25);
-o-transform: scale(0.25);
-ms-transform:scale(0.25);
transform:scale(0.25); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s26cm/

Comment: unfortunaly this is only available for modern browsers, and I need to keep IE7+ in the role ... it's absurd how many IE7 visits we have on the website :/ - I will give it a try though, but I wish it could be as easier for legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: instead of `px` one can use `%` if the font-size is to be scaled accordingly to it's relative elements, else `em` if it needs to be scaled accordingly to the entire page's font size, while shrinking the div , shrink the font correspondingly

`12pt = 16px = 1em = 100%` this may come handy for changing font size units

assign `id` or `class` to that div and use those as selectors in script to change the size after the *save* button is clicked, it will override the inline styling, can you post a fiddle sir?

Answer (score 0):

"How can I shrink a div when it has inline styling?"

Do you mean:

```
display: inline;
```

If you do – Anything set to display inline will not accept width properties.
Switch to inline-block;

Comment: shrink in propotion to that preview page